# 2d Camera Not following Sprite Correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, xna-3.0

I need help with a camera following a sprite. I have a camera class which isn't following the sprite properly. My camera class is

```
camera cam;
cam.position = sprite.position;
```

this piece of the code isn't executing properly. everytime I run this code it resets my sprite as if it was in position (0,0) and then follows my sprite. Here's a [video example](http://screencast.com/t/gc2UOyaV) of what I'm talking about.
The position of my sprite is at (60,515).

```cs
class Camera2d
{
    public float _zoom;
    public Matrix _transform;
    public Vector2 _position;
    protected float _rotation;

    public Camera2d()
    {
        _zoom = 1.0f;
        _rotation = 0.0f;
        _position = Vector2.Zero;
    }
    //public float Zoom {  }
    //public float Rotation {  }
    public void Move(Vector2 amount)
    {
        _position += amount;
    }
    public Vector2 CPos
    {
        get { return _position; }
        set { _position = value; }
    }
    public Matrix get_tranformation(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        _transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(-_position.X, -_position.Y, 0));

        return _transform;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at a sprite offset problem. The difference between your sprite's position and your camera's position is nothing. Therefore your sprite will appear to always be located at {0, 0}.

If you offset your camera's position by half of it's view height and width then it will appear to center your sprite.

```
cam.position = sprite.position;
cam.position.x -= cam.width / 2;
cam.position.y -= cam.height / 2;
```